# Proper way to add an RPM spec file to an existing source code repo

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have an existing source code repo with a Makefile. `make install` at the root of that code repo will build the software and put it in in `/tmp/install/` or some other directory as defined by an environment variable.

I'm trying to add an rpm spec file to that repo, to build a package.

I'm very confused on how to run `make install` from my source code root in the spec file. The first thing rpm build does is to cd to `~/rpmbuild/BUILD`.

Most the guides I have seen mention unpacking a source package to `~/rpmbuild/BUILD` as a first step prior to running rpmbuild, but I already have a git checkout of the sources and would like to avoid unnecessary copies.

What's the proper way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

That is the way to do it. You could make use of [tito](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/tito), which helps you creating rpms from git repositories.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do it is to use GNU coding standards with the `make` targets. So [have your `make install` respect `DESTDIR`](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html) and then you'll be able to use a super-simple specfile that just calls `%mke_install` and everything "just works."